# Upload multiple files in a JSP

Tags: java, struts

How to upload multiple files in a JSP?

I have a list of eight Questions, I want attachments for each question, when I am submitting the form I am getting the following error. Please help me in solving this

```
"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke 
  com.usrinfo.form.AssessmentForm.setAttatchment on bean class 
  'class com.usrinfo.form.AssessmentForm' - argument type mismatch - 
  had objects of type "java.util.ArrayList" but expected 
  signature "org.apace.struts.upload.FormFile"
```

this is my input type:

```
<input class="" type='file' style="display:none;" name="attachment" id="<%=q.getId()%>file"/>
```

This is my action

```
action="xxx.do"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Can you show us the piece of code where this happens?

Comment: action="xxxxx.do"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> while sending it to the bean class it showing error my bean class is like  :                                                         private FormFile attachment;

 
 public FormFile getAttachment() {
  return attachment;
 }

 
 public void setAttachment(FormFile attachment) {
  this.attachment = attachment;
 }
}Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your code in question properly

Comment: Please update the question with your code instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: Edit your question and upload the code, that made easy to read

Comment: We'll also need the JSP code you use to upload the file. Your error indicates that your upload does not match your backing bean.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like **HTML or JSP**.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.  Also be sure to check the preview of your message.  It would have been obvious that something was wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the message, Struts is trying to set a `List<FormFile>` on your `AssessmentForm`, but your `AssessmentForm` class only has `setAttachment(FormFile)`. If you change it to `List<FormFile>`, Struts will be able to set the list of `FormFiles` and you can iterate over that to process them.

Comment: Thank you @mthmulders i solved that problem using list<FormFile>

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have got file data some thing like this "B@5c3dad" how to retrieve the actual data

Comment: If you run into new issues, it would be best to ask a new question. That way this question doesn't get cluttered with many different questions, and thus it will be more helpful when other read this page.