# How to read data from a multiple Files and stores it in another files

Tags: java

Hi I have list of file,I want to read the data from each file and  want to store in a seperate files.Iam not getting thought how to do it Can any one help in this... Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you not getting , you read a file, create another file and dump the entire stream there !

Comment: Please read the [FAQ].

Comment: possible duplicate of [File I/O: Reading from one file and writing to another (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588525/file-i-o-reading-from-one-file-and-writing-to-another-java)

Comment: I have A list of FormFiles which i got from the jsp page. I want to read Each File data and to store them in a seperate file

Comment: kindly post, whatever you have tried, don't put your homework here, we are here to solve your problems not your homework..

Comment: If this question is a follow up to [your previous question[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609403/upload-multiple-files-in-a-jsp/) you should supply a bit more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File path=new File("D:\\FileSource");
    File[] listOfFiles = path.listFiles();
    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\DestFile\\outPut.txt"));
    String s=new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file = listOfFiles[i];
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((s=br.readLine())!=null){
                bw.write(s);
            }
        }
    }
   bw.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Read data from a file and store in a separate file means copying. You can use

```
java.nio.file.Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
```

Comment: Note that you need Java 7 for @Evgeniy's answer to work.